# php single entry associative array

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I get data from a .xlsx file, which I also put into an array(named $tableArray, I used PHPExcel for that). now i don't know how I can output even a single entry in my array.

I tried

```
$tableArray[1];
```

getting all the entries works with

```
var_dump($tableArray);
```

my code:

```
            <?php
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($fileName);
        $excelReader->setReadDataOnly();
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($fileName);
        $excelObj->getActiveSheet()->toArray(); 
        $worksheetNames = $excelObj->getSheetNames($fileName);
        $tableArray = array();

        foreach($worksheetNames as $key => $sheetName){
            $excelObj->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheetName);
            $tableArray[$sheetName] = $excelObj->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
        }       

        var_dump($tableArray);
        ?>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something more specific?  This should be just as easy as `echo $tableArray['someKey'];` if you want to echo a specific value, or you can use a `foreach()` loop to loop through your array and echo out values.  Use the results of that `var_dump()` to help yourself understand the structure of your array.

Comment: @Squeegy06 from var_dump($tableArray) i get this: http://pastebin.com/tEF7cZdG, but what i need to know is how i can access a single entry in this array, and the single attributes, i don't know which index i need to use to access a single entry.

Comment: I posted an answer to help get you started, but really this question is better fit for a tutorial on PHP Arrays.  Stackoverflow focuses more on answering specific programming challenges, this question is more in the realm of the need for a tutorial and those types of answers don't fit here in long form.  I linked codeacademy in the answer, but there are other great websites that teach the basics of PHP.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few tips to help get you started.

If you want to see your array in a cleaner format on your browser, surround the `var_dump()` in a `<pre>` tag like so.

```
<?php

$myArray = [
    "orange" => "foo",
    "bar" => [
        "test" => "more"
    ]
];

?>
<pre>
    <?php var_dump($myArray); ?>
</pre>
```

This will help you understand your array structure better as it will be easier to read.

Accessing values in arrays is as easy as referencing the key.  For example in the array above, if we want the value of orange, just `echo $myArray["orange"];`

If the value is another array, such as the key `bar`, and we want the value of `test`, we can just reference both keys in order `echo $myArray["bar"]["test"];`

You can use `foreach()` to loop through your array and perform action on each key => value pair.

```
<?php

$myArray = [
    "orange" => "foo",
    "bar" => [
        "test" => "more"
    ]
];

foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($value);
}
```

If you're looking for more detailed information I'd recommend going through some of the courses on [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/).  It will help you not only with this question, but others involving basic functionality of PHP.

Hope this helps!